# How to prevent the same multiplication numbers being asked twice in a row

Tags: java, random

sorry to bother you once again but I have one more add on to be made to this program. It works fine but how could it be made so it wouldn't ask the same multiplication question twice in a row? For example when it asks what is 1*2 it shouldn't ask it again right away (although there's only a small chance on that).

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  boolean correctAnswer;
  Random number = new Random();
  int nmb1;
  int nmb2;
  int multi;


  while (true) {
    nmb1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
    nmb2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
    multi = nmb1 * nmb2;

    // read the user's input ...
    do {
        correctAnswer = multiplication(nmb1,nmb2,multi);
    }
    while (correctAnswer != true);
    // .. and repeat until the user types the correct answer

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Right");
  }
   }


  public static boolean multiplication(int number1,int number2,int answer)
  {

  int question;

     question = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is" + number1 + "*" + number2));

      if (question != answer) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, try again");

          return false;
      }

  return true;

  }

}
```

Comment: Store the multiplication-pairs that were asked and dont ask them again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, in this example, It computes all combinations of number pair, and then It shuffle the number pairs and finally It asks for every number pair.

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean correctAnswer;
        int nmb1;
        int nmb2;
        int multi;

        // It computes all combinations
        List<int[]> asks = new ArrayList<>(100);
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
                asks.add(new int[]{i,j});
            }
        }

        // It shufles
        Collections.shuffle(asks);

        // It asks for every number pair
        for (int[] numbers : asks){ // instead of while(true)
            nmb1 = numbers[0];
            nmb2 = numbers[1];
            multi = nmb1 * nmb2;

            // read the user's input ...

            ...
        }
```